# whats the correct way to be back to top view controller in the navigation controller stack?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayMVR.png

Sorry, I am a beginner, I am worried that I will make something weird if I do something wrong later.

if I have 3 view controllers like the picture above,and in the 3rd view controller I have an alert that sent me back to the 1st view controller after pressing the alert  like the code below :

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Great", message: "lets get back to VC1", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let alertAction1 = UIAlertAction(title: "back", style: .default) { (action) in


            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)


        }

        alert.addAction(alertAction1)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }


}
```

there are 2 ways to be back to first view controller, by using

```
1. self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

or by using `2. perform segue with identifier` , what is the correct way to be back to the first view controller? the first one or the second? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way is

```
  1. self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

also check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html) out because you will understand why it is better (clear navigation stack)

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct way

```
1. self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

segue will make them all remain in stack

Comment: Sure, segue will just put a new controller on the top.